The trace of a constant function $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ implies $u = 0 \:a.e.$?
What I want to prove is that if the $T_r(u) = 0$, then $u=0\: a.e.$ if $u(x)=C\:a.e.$. This particular case $\partial\Omega$ is $C^1$ and $\Omega$ is bounded. The thing is that the border has mesure $0$, so I dont really know if I can conclude something. In my specific case I proved $\nabla u = 0\:a.e.$.
I already know that $\text{Ker}(T_r) = H^1_0(\Omega)$.
